# What does mean by "algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb Q_p$"?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I want to understand the precise meaning of "algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$".

- What does mean by "algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb Q_p$" ? Isn't it just the set $\bar{\mathbb Q} \cap \mathbb Q_p$ ?

This set may be think of as "set of algebraic numbers" or even "set of $p$-adic algebraic numbers". It is closed field but not complete with respect $p$-adic topology.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't take the intersection of $\bar{\mathbb Q}$ and $\mathbb Q_p$ because these aren't subsets of some common ambient set.

By definition if $L/K$ is a field extension (not necessarily algebraic) then you define the "algebraic closure of $L$ in $K$" as the set

$$\{\alpha\in L\mid\text{$\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$}\}$$

which is always a subfield of $L$.

Comment: I think $\mathbb{C}_p :=\widehat{\bar{\mathbb Q}}_p$ is the ambient space containing both $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q_p$ ?  I found something [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17032/which-p-adic-numbers-are-also-algebraic?_gl=1*1dggqun*_ga*NTM5NjM3MDY3LjE2NzEzMzEzODM.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY4MTMzODY2Ny4xMDEuMS4xNjgxMzQwNDA4LjAuMC4w)

Comment: Sure i guess it depends on your definition of $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$..... if you take $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ to be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ inside $\mathbb C_p$ then yes you can take this intersection and it's the same thing as what I defined above

Comment: yes, thanks for comment